# what is the equivalent of `shell=True` in `paramiko`?

Tags: python, shell, ssh, subprocess, paramiko

I'm using `paramiko`'s  [SSHClient](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html) to control a server via `exec_command` method. However, I'm failing to use python over there because it says `python not found` and I realized the entire `conda` enviroment is not there. On my local machine, I get around it with `shell=True` passed to `subprocess`. Question: how do I do this on paramiko, or, is there another command that I should run to get `conda` to be loaded up in server's shell.

EDIT: the `exec_command` offers `environment` optional keyword but I don't know how to leverage it if it is useful at all.

Comment: sshd _always_ runs a shell. paramiko has no equivalent to `shell=False`, because there's no way to tell the remote server not to start one.

Comment: More likely what you're depending on is the remote shell being considered a _login_ shell, which influences which dotfiles it chooses to execute.

Comment: (when you pass a command, you don't get a login shell by default; that's not specific to paramiko; the regular command-line ssh client works the same way).

Comment: ...compare `ssh somehost` and then running `python` once it's in (which gets a login shell) to `ssh somehost python` (which starts Python from a noninteractive shell). There's still a shell in either case, but which dotfiles it runs is different.

Comment: ...once you've reproduced this from a command line, you can iterate more quickly on deciding what kind of solution you want. One ugly hack is just to source the files you want explicitly: `ssh somehost 'for f in .bashrc .profile .bash_profile; do [ -s "$f" ] && . "$f"; done; python'` -- if it works from your shell command line, it'll work from paramiko too.

Comment: (Does the above make sense? I'm going to wait until you've got follow-up questions before elaborating further).

Comment: makes a lot of sense, I'm reading it over and over, its just the gap between 250k points person with 1k person. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: For some general background on which dotfiles are read during shell startup under which conditions, see the *Invocation* section of `man bash`. Once you've done that, and figured out which specific dotfiles are setting up what your Python environment needs, you should be in a better place to decide what kind of solution you want to implement.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Solved! thanks for all the comments. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to insightful comments by @CharesDuffy with "don't feed me teach me how to fish" style, I solved the problem as follows:

For conda/miniconda to be loaded, I prefaced my commands with `source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate;`.

Enriching points:

- For a permanent solution, the preface can be added to `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` which is what is loaded up by default when ssh'ing. If you have a fresh installation e.g. a virtual machine, those files don't exist in the first place.
- sourcing that conda file is paramount (as opposed to *executing* it)

Ostensibly, `shell=True` kwarg of `subprocess` module is doing something like this behind the scenes.